# Python line chart from complicated txt data

Tags: python, charts

I have a text file in the form:

Time,secs    AreaA,cm˛   AreaA,A˛    AreaB,cm˛   AreaB,A˛    PiA,mN/m    S.Pot,mV    Depth,mm    T.A.,cm˛
1.103000    342.385783  44.343862   -0.278713   NaN 0.060977    -2.867612   5.000000
2.233000    342.357189  44.340159   -0.278713   NaN 0.069688    -5.336944   5.000000
3.356000    342.128434  44.310532   -0.202736   NaN 0.087109    -8.045245   5.000000
4.488000    341.999759  44.293867   -0.202736   NaN 0.093643    0.318624    5.000000

I would like to create a linear graph for `x` data - `AreA,cm` and `y` data - `PiA,mN/m`.

Unfortunately I am not able to skip the first line and the data will not load correctly.

I'm trying this one:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open('v10.txt') as f:
    data = np.loadtxt(f, delimiter="\t", dtype='float',skiprows=0,)

x = data[:, 1]
y = data[:, 5]
fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle('')
plt.xlabel('')
plt.ylabel('')
plt.plot(-x, -y, c='r', label='')

leg = plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Anyone can know how to do it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you please show the code you are using to read in and plot this data? It would be even more helpful to us if you could create a [mcve]

Comment: import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open('v10.txt') as f:
    data = np.loadtxt(f, delimiter="\t", dtype='float',skiprows=0,)

x = data[:, 1]
y = data[:, 5]
fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle('')
plt.xlabel('')
plt.ylabel('')
plt.plot(-x, -y, c='r', label='')

leg = plt.legend()
plt.show()

Comment: You should edit your question with the code, don't post it in the comments

Comment: You edited your question with my solution below :) Smart

Comment: I'm very sorry, a lot of open cards with all kinds of solutions. First contact with the python, and I need it urgently for my master's thesis

Comment: Put `skiprows=1,` in your code instead of `skiprows=0,`. OR try replacing `file.txt` in my code to `v10.txt` and re-run it

Comment: I tried this and that. Blank chart all the time

Comment: Try printing `x` and `y`. What do you get?

Comment: Yes, I add plt.show() and nothing

Comment: I mean before plotting, write ‘print (x,y)’ and tell me what is printed on the screen

Comment: [342.385783, 342.357189, 342.128434, ... , 21.613734] [nan, nan, ..., nan, nan]

Comment: Shouldn't be y = [float(line.split('\t')[5]) for line in lines[1:]]?

Comment: It looks that for some Reason 6th column corrspondbto NaN in your file. So try replacing y=data[:,5] by data[:,6]

Comment: You see the problem after print. Your `y` values are `nan`. Thats why you don't see anything on the plot

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the data provided by you. You just have to skip the first line in the file while accessing its contents

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open("file.txt") as f: 
    lines = f.readlines() 

x = [float(line.split()[1]) for line in lines[1:]] # [1:] skips the first line
y = [float(line.split()[4]) for line in lines[1:]]

xmesh = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 100) # Create a fine x mesh for fitting
fit = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x,y,1)) # Making a linear fit

plt.plot(x, y, 'bo', label='Actual data') # Plotting actual data
plt.plot(xmesh, fit(xmesh), '-b', label='Linear fit') # Plotting fit
plt.xlabel('Area (cm)')
plt.ylabel('Pi A (mN/m)')
plt.legend()
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I do not see any data on the chart trying this :(

Comment: Did you create a file named `file.txt` and put the first 4 lines of your data in that file?

Answer (score 0):

Solution using pandas (which you can install using `$ pip install pandas`)

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filepath = 'path/to/file.txt'
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep=r'\s+')

area_key = 'AreaA,cm˛'  # watch out for unicode '˛'
pi_key = 'PiA,mN/m'

ax = df.plot(area_key, pi_key, 'scatter', label='data')  # can pass any plt kwargs here

x = df[area_key]
y = df[pi_key]

xmesh = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 100) # Create a fine x mesh for fitting
fit = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x,y,1)) # Making a linear fit 

# cam override x/y labels titles here
ax.plot(xmesh, fit(xmesh), label='linear fit')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]